# Checked event isn't fired in checkbox in listbox

Tags: c#, xaml

Hi i'm creating an checklistbox

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox" Content="{Binding Path=Info.Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainViewModel}}, Path=SimpleCommand}">

            </CheckBox>
            <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=Status}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

but when i check the simplecommand isn't call

```
 SimpleCommand = new RelayCommand(obj => MessageBox.Show("alert"), obj => true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the control name rather than the viewmodel for ancestor type

```
<CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox" 
    Content="{Binding Path=Info.Name}" 
    IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}" 
    Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=SimpleCommand}"/>
```

Comment: thanks this works very well...can explain why using viewmodel like source doesn't work?

Comment: XAML looks for Controls only.If you want the view Model you can use the Control.DataContext. And accept the answer plz :)

Comment: sorry is my first time on stackoverflow...thanks a lot